# Select with error Illegal mix of collations

Tags: mysql

I have mysql clause:

```
Select * from table where firstname like 'INPUT'
```

I'm trying enter INPUT for display error:

`Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'`

I setted variable:

[image]

I'm tried enter emoji but still display error.

Can you help me in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query:

```
select * from table_name where firstname like 'INPUT';
```

table is a keyword so try giving the name of the table instead in the query.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get this error is because your column `firstname` is in the character set `utf8` (alias for `utf8mb3`) which can not represent characters requiring 4 bytes (all emoji characters fall in this category).

One way to solve it is to change the character set on `firstname` to `utf8mb4`. This does however come with the drawback that you can only have a varchar be 191 characters long if it has an index on it.

```sql
alter table `table` modify `firstname` varchar(191) character set utf8mb4;
```